# What are the concepts of "kernel ring buffer", "user level", "log level"?

Tags: kernel, logs

I often saw the words "kernel ring buffer", "user level", "log level" and some other words appear together. e.g.

> /var/log/dmesg Contains kernel ring buffer information.
>
> /var/log/kern.log Contains only the kernel's messages of any loglevel
>
> /var/log/user.log Contains information about all user level logs

Are they all about logs? How are they related and different?

By "level", I would imagine a hierarchy of multiple levels?

Is "user level" related to "user space"?

Are they related to [runlevel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel) or [protection ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28computer_security%29) in some way?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Yes, all of this has to do with logging. No, none of it has to do with runlevel or "protection ring".

The kernel keeps its logs in a ring buffer. The main reason for this is so that the logs from the system startup get saved until the syslog daemon gets a chance to start up and collect them. Otherwise there would be no record of any logs prior to the startup of the syslog daemon. The contents of that ring buffer can be seen at any time using the `dmesg` command, and its contents are also saved to `/var/log/dmesg` just as the syslog daemon is starting up.

All logs that do not come from the kernel are sent as they are generated to the syslog daemon so they are not kept in any buffers. The kernel logs are also picked up by the syslog daemon as they are generated but they also continue to be saved (unnecessarily, arguably) to the ring buffer.

The log levels can be seen documented in the [syslog(3) manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/syslog) and are as follows:

- **LOG_EMERG**: system is unusable
- **LOG_ALERT**: action must be taken immediately
- **LOG_CRIT**: critical conditions
- **LOG_ERR**: error conditions
- **LOG_WARNING**: warning conditions
- **LOG_NOTICE**: normal, but significant, condition
- **LOG_INFO**: informational message
- **LOG_DEBUG**: debug-level message

Each level is designed to be less "important" than the previous one. A log file that records logs at one level will also record logs at all of the more important levels too.

The difference between `/var/log/kern.log` and `/var/log/mail.log` (for example) is not to do with the level but with the facility, or category. The categories are also documented on the manpage.

Comment: Thanks. (1) Is "user level" related to "user space"? (2) From what you said, `/var/log/kern.log` and `/var/log/dmesg` should have the same content as the kernel messages? But their contents are not the same.

Comment: "user level" isn't a thing, as far as I know. There is the syslog level, which is the "importance" level of a syslog message (I listed the levels), and it doesn't have anything to do with user space vs. kernel space. `/var/log/kern.log` should contain the `dmesg` content (perhaps formatted differently) from boot time. Unless it has been a long time since boot and those contents have been rotated out.

Comment: My second question is: While `dmesg` prints out the current values of kernel ring buffer, the past/old values of the buffer are stored in `/var/log/dmesg`. So `dmesg` output is just a recent subset of  `/var/log/dmesg` content, and they are different. Then are the contents of `/var/log/dmesg` (not `dmesg` as in your comment) and `/var/log/kernel.log` the same?

Comment: Depends when! Soon after boot, the `/var/log/dmesg` content will likely be near the end of `/var/log/kern.log`. Much later on, it won't be there, it will have rotated out. In general, `/var/log/kern.log` will contain logs that are older than any given snapshot of the kernel's log ring buffer and also logs that are newer than the snapshot.

Comment: [This video explains the circular buffer pretty well](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gYxdHbbjn_8)

Comment: However obvious it may seem, I believe an important point about kernel ring buffer is that it's of fixed size and contains only the latest messages.

Comment: On my ubuntu machine which has run for more than 2 weeks, the `dmesg -k` reveals much more info than the /var/log/kern.log file. And it seems `dmesg -k` contains the log from the boot of the machine. Not sure where it gets those from. May be from the `/var/log/dmesg.0`. And there are also some numbered archived logs like `/var/log/dmesg.N.gz`.

Answer (score 25):

*To answer at least the first part of your question about `dmesg`:*

`/var/log/dmesg` stores the content of the 'kernel ring buffer', a memory buffer created by the kernel at boot in which to store log data it generates as soon as you get past the bootloader phase.

A ring buffer is a special kind of buffer that is always a constant size, removing the oldest messages when new messages come in. 
The text stored in the kernel ring buffer is what you see flashing past you on-screen when you first boot a Unix-like machine in console mode (no splash screen, Plymouth). The kernel log is stored in a memory buffer so that boot logs have somewhere to be, until the system has bootstrapped itself to the point where the `syslog` daemon can take over.

`dmesg` under Linux is a part of the essential `util-linux` package of  system maintenance tools published by kernel.org. According to the `dmesg(1)` man page,

> dmesg is used to examine or control the kernel ring buffer.

See: http://www.computerhope.com/unix/dmesg.htm

Under 'systemd' init, this command can be used to print the kernel ring buffer:
`# journalctl --dmesg or journalctl -k`, thxs for correction @don_crissti

Issuing the command `dmesg | grep -i ethernet`
for example, will parse the kernel ring buffer for the string 'ethernet'.

I hope this helps at least with the first part of your inquiry.